# Wordpress xmlprc not working in https

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony, xml-rpc

Recently, I have updated my site using an SSL and all URIs are now "https://".

My site is developed with Symfony 2 and mixing a Wordpress installation inside Symfony 2 `web/wordpress` directory.

All regular access is fine. Only one question:

In my Symfony 2, there is this code snippet:

```
private function getRecentPosts($num = 4)
{
    require_once 'wordpress/wp-includes/class-IXR.php';

    $user      = '11111';
    $pwd       = '22222';

    $host='https://www.rsywx.net';
    $script='/wordpress/xmlrpc.php';
    $port=443;

    $client = new \IXR_Client($host, $script, $port);

    $params = array(0, $user, $pwd, $num);
    $client->query('metaWeblog.getRecentPosts', $params);

    $wp = $client->getResponse();

    return $wp;
}
```

When my site is not wrapped with https, the above code works fine. But now it is under https, the above code is not working. If I dump the `$client` variable after the `query` function call, it gives an error like:

```
+error: IXR_Error {#256 ▼
    +code: -32300
    +message: "transport error - could not open socket"
```

Any hints? Do I need to tweak my WP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just avoided using XMLRPC at all to solve this.

In my Symfony 2 application, I just used a 2nd database to directly access the underlying wordpress database. It is a hack but it resolves my issue for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was on the file *wp-includes/class-IXR.php*, it doesn't work with HTTPS, you must use also *class-wp-http-ixr-client.php* . And don't forget to include the configuration file *wp-load.php*.

The code snippet will be:

```
private function getRecentPosts($num = 4) 
{
    include 'wordpress/wp-load.php';
    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . 'wordpress/wp-includes/class-IXR.php';
    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . 'wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-http-ixr-client.php';


    $user      = '11111';
    $pwd       = '22222';

    //Deprecated
    /*
    $host='https://www.rsywx.net';
    $script='/wordpress/xmlrpc.php';
    $port=443;
    $client = new \IXR_Client($host, $script, $port);
    */
    $client = new WP_HTTP_IXR_CLIENT('https://www.rsywx.net/wordpress/xmlrpc.php');

    $params = array(0, $user, $pwd, $num);
    $client->query('metaWeblog.getRecentPosts', $params);

    $wp = $client->getResponse();

    return $wp;
}
```